# Android - Overflow Menu and Back Button not showing in Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design, androiddesignsupport

I'm trying to implement features from the new Design Support Library to create a parallax scrolling toolbar which looks similar to the new material design WhatsApp profile pages. However, I can't get the overflow menu and back button to show in the top corners.

I have tried using the following methods to display the back button, but none of them works.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

And overwriting the onCreateOptionsMenu method for the overflow menu also didn't work.

Does anyone know how to add these toolbar icons to a CollapsingToolbar from the Design Support Library? Below is my layout xml for the activity. Thanks!

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/primary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/headerbg"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issue, none from existing answers have helped me, surprising fix of my problem was in question description.

---

### Solution for AppCompat Activity

So working collapsing toolbar with back button needs those few lines in controller `onCreate` method:

```
//change id to Your id
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); 
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//this line shows back button
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Manifest of this activity ( notice **parentActivityName** attribute ):

```
<activity
  android:name=".SomeActivity"
  android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

Template part:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

---

### Alternative solution ( also AppCompat Activity )

Controller `onCreate` method:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

toolbar.setNavigationIcon(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            onBackPressed();
        }
});
```

This approach uses the same manifest and template presented in first solution.

Answer (score 15):

In my case this works! `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` inside toolbar layout

Comment: What do you mean "toolbar layout"?

Comment: He means add `app:layout_collapseMode="pin` to `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` like this ```<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />```

Answer (score 9):

Try not to put this in the coordinatorLayout:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

It works for me. No idea why. Good luck

Comment: Also try adding toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); to initialize the background color to transparent. Sometimes it puts a cool effect

Answer (score 3):

The following enables the Navigation Button:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp, null));
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //onBackPressed()
    }
});
```

To get the Overflow Menu behavior you have to declare a menu.xml file with showAsAction:never applied to your menu items like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_one"
        android:title="action 1"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_two"
        android:title="action 2"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

And inflate it like:

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_one:
                break;
            case R.id.action_two:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem for me

Comment: Pretty bad that we have to manually add the back button just for this.

Answer (score 0):

change 
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
to
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
in imageView.
hope this will work for you

Comment: it worked for me, but i changed collapseMode to "pin" for both image and toolbar.. will update reason soon.

Comment: You can see the difference between pin and parallax here.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html

Comment: In PIN Collapse, when view collapse it holds top area and rest area got collapsed but in parralex it holds center area.

Answer (score 0):

If u have not added parentActivityName tag in manifest file, then do so by adding following lines of code as

```
<activity android:name=".Activity.MovieData"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity.Home">
</activity>
```

where "Activity" is my Package name
"MovieData" is my activity name
"Home" is my destination activity name

EDIT: If you are supporting android api level 15 and below then parentActivityName wont work.

To support lower versions, u need to add meta-data tag as

```
<meta-data
    android:name="PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value="com.example.Activity.Home"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

change this..

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:elevation="15dp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:logo="@drawable/action_bar_logo"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

the popupTheme makes the difference and it is what you were looking for..

this is my full xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".AddUser">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:elevation="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:logo="@drawable/action_bar_logo"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <include layout="@layout/content_add_user" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Good luck!

Comment: This example doesn't use CollapsingToolbarLayout. How does this answer the question?

Comment: genious correcting other people's mistakes since 2016!, I really don't know what I was thinking, but you are rigth..

Answer (score -1):

Goto res/values/ and open styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Change parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" to parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"

Then start debugging and remove all unnecessary code like `//  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` things.
Definitely work.